# How to bring my parents for visit UK

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, moldovan-citizens

I am citizen of Romania with pre-Settlement status, living in the UK with British partner for 4 years. We are expecting a baby in 2 months and I would like to invite my parents, who are citizens of Moldova (non EU country), to visit us.

What documents and subjective steps you can advise in this case.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done up to now? How long do you want you parents to visit for? Assuming it’s 6 months or less, you can find out pretty much everything you need to know from here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y If you’ve got specific question(s) after reading this info you can edit your question.